HP Spectre x360 Laptop - Black Screen After Installing Ubuntu Studio 24.10
I have a high-end HP Spectre x360 2-in-1 Laptop (16-aa0006nl). Every time I try to install Ubuntu Studio 24.10, I get a black screen on boot, and I end up having to reinstall Windows. It seems like my graphics cards aren’t being recognized. It’s a shame because I love Ubuntu Studio and all the extra capabilities it offers compared to Windows.
The installation happens perfectly and then I get black screen after rebooting.
I also tried installing version 24.04 and had similar issues.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Should I wait for the next release?
Thank you for any help!
SPECS:

PROCESSOR:
Name                           Manufacturer NumberOfCores NumberOfLogicalProcessors
----                           ------------ ------------- -------------------------
Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 7 155H GenuineIntel            16                        22

MOTHERBOARD:
Product Manufacturer SerialNumber
------- ------------ ------------
8C17    HP           PTMFR028JJB05W

RAM:
  Capacity Manufacturer PartNumber           Speed
   -------- ------------ ----------           -----
16GB         SK Hynix     H58G66BK7BX067        7467mhz/s
16GB         SK Hynix     H58G66BK7BX067        7467mhz/s

SSD:
Model                                  Size Manufacturer           SerialNumber
-----                                  ---- ------------           ------------
WD PC SN810 SDCPNRY-1T00-1006 1024203640320 (unità disco standard) E823_8FA6_BF53_0001_001B_448B_476E_6B1C.

GRAPHIC CARDS:

Name                               AdapterRAM
----                               ----------
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4050 Laptop GPU 4293918720
Intel(R) Arc(TM) Graphics           134217728


What are the specs of the computer? CPU/Graphics?

I wrote it to the main question

You say you get a black screen on boot. Is that before installation? Or is it that the installation happens perfectly and you get black screen after rebooting

installation happens perfectly and then i get black screen after rebooting, also using again the same USB where ubuntu is installed

Please don't attach picture of specs. Those are not machine readable and will not be read by search engines.

if i upgrade from 24.0.1 it works... but I had troubles with qjack and my soundcard so I uinstalled ubuntu studio 24.10 and putted windows again.. I'm so sad, with my old pc it was working good, i hope they do an upgrade and solve all bugs
